# How to fix a CSRF verification error?

Tags: python, django, templates, csrf

I am getting the error, "CSRF token missing or incorrect" though I believe I have included the right tag within the template.  Below is the view and template that have been showing this error:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/contact_form.html',{'form': form})
```

Template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact us</h1>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you view the templates HTML source do you see the csrf token field being set?

Comment: Also make sure that you have added the middleware to the settings.py or are using the @csrf_protect decorator.

Comment: Check this on how to use it in your app: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice item 3 of [the instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it). A quick way to do this is to replace your `render_to_response` call with `render(request, 'reserve/templates/contact_form.html',{'form': form})` (import it via `from django.shortcuts import render`).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a context instance to your render_to_response

```
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('reserve/templates/contact_form.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'form': form}))
```